# If two points fall on the exact same position, is the resulting overlap considered as 1 point or 2 points?

Tags: soft-question

Two points, $a$ and $b$, both lie on $(1,1)$. Visually this has the appearance of one point. Have the two points 'merged' into one? Is the resulting point able to just be considered a single point $(1,1)$? Or, are they like two points stacked on top of one another that you can't see?

Comment: I would consider them as two separate points with the same position

Comment: they are two - like twins

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with it/them. As long as you make your preference clear when writing up what you're doing, no one can complain.